# Does BigQuery's 1,000-table in a query limit apply to wildcards?

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have 2,000 tables that I'd like to union together, can I do that using a wildcard query, like [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables)?

Or does the [1,000-tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy) referenced per query limit still apply?

Answer (score 1):

> does the 1,000-tables referenced per query limit still apply?

Yes. It still applies!

BigQuery looks for how many tables involved in query (no matter what exactly syntax/functionality is used). If you explicitely list all needed tables or using wildcard - at the end it is the same number of tables to be involved  - thus same limitation applied

Note: *partitions in partitioned table are not considered as a separate tables*

Comment: side notes: there's also a max number of partitions per query, and for a large number of partitions/tables performance can be affected negatively